# EF MVC Linq - Error passing model to a MVC WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

When I try to pass the results of a Linq query in to a MVC.Webgrid I am getting the error (simplified):

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of 
type'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery but 
this dictionary requires a model item of type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyModel.Models.MyMetric]'
```

This is the ActionResult that fails:

```
 public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var metrics = db.Metrics
            .GroupBy(c => c.Year)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Year = g.Key,
                Q1 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 1).Sum(c => c.Value),
                Q2 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 2).Sum(c => c.Value),
                Q3 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 3).Sum(c => c.Value),
                Q4 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 4).Sum(c => c.Value)
            });                        
        return View(metrics);
    }
```

I assume that since I am creating a pivot of the original data that I need to create some sort of new model but I am unsure how to do that in this context. (just geting my feet wet with EF and MVC)

Any ideas?

TIA
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an anonymous type to the view whereas you should pass an `IEnumerable<MyMetric>`. So, assuming that `MyMetric` looks like this:

```
public class MyMetric
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Q1 { get; set; }
    public int Q2 { get; set; }
    public int Q3 { get; set; }
    public int Q4 { get; set; }
}
```

you simply need to return an `IEnumerable<MyMetric>` from your LINQ query:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var metrics = db.Metrics
        .GroupBy(c => c.Year)
        .Select(g => new MyMetric
        {
            Year = g.Key,
            Q1 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 1).Sum(c => c.Value),
            Q2 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 2).Sum(c => c.Value),
            Q3 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 3).Sum(c => c.Value),
            Q4 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 4).Sum(c => c.Value)
        });                        
    return View(metrics);
}
```

Comment: So I would need to create the MyMetric class? As I currently have it I am just returning the results of the "query" as the anonymous type.

Comment: Yes, you have to create MyMetrics class. This is called view model. You cannot pass anonymous objects to views.

Comment: I'm missing something somplace in your answer. I have tried implementing your sample and still get the same error. How does "MyMetric" cause "metrics" to become IEnumerable?

Comment: Notice the `.Select` clause in my answer: `.Select(g => new MyMetric`. Now look at yours: `.Select(g => new`. Notice the difference? This is where the result becomes an `IEnumerable<MyMetric>`, whereas in your case you are using an anonymous type.

Comment: Thanks for your patience on this, I should have clarified:  I did put together the class MyMetric and included the "new MyMetric" as in your example but I still get the same error.

Comment: Is your view strongly typed to `@model IEnumerable<MyMetric>`? Also try calling `.ToList()`: `return View(metrics.ToList());`.

Comment: Bingo! I had forgotten to change the @model on my view.  I really appreciate your help in moving my knowledge forward.